# How to compare unicode string with the value from input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, comparison

I am very confused about how to compare unicode string in javascript, and I do not even know how to search the problem.

Does any one know why the string from a html input is not same as a unicode string, even when they are visually same.

```js
s1 = '\u00c3\u00a4pple' 
s2 = 'äpple'
s3 = document.querySelector('#myword').value // äpple

// s1.value.normalize() === s2.normalize() will be true
// s1.value.normalize() === s3.normalize() will be false ? why
// s3.value.normalize() === s2.normalize() will be false ? why
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a Unicode problem.

Strings in JavaScript are sequences of code units. Reasonable you could expect that string comparison involves the evaluation of code units for a match.

```
const firstStr = 'hello';
const secondStr = '\u0068ell\u006F';
console.log(firstStr === secondStr); // => true
```

firstStr and secondStr strings have the same sequence of code units. Reasonable they are equal.

Suppose you want to compare two strings that rendered look the same but contain different code unit sequences. Then you may have an unexpected result, because strings that visually look the same are not equal in a comparison:

```
const str1 = 'ça va bien';
const str2 = 'c\u0327a va bien';
console.log(str1);          // => 'ça va bien'
console.log(str2);          // => 'ça va bien'
console.log(str1 === str2); // => false
```

str1 and str2 when rendered look the same, but have different code units.
It happens because ç grapheme can be constructed in two ways:

```
Using U+00E7 LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
Or using a combining character sequence: U+0063 LATIN SMALL LETTER C plus the combining mark U+0327 COMBINING CEDILLA.
```

Reference Links:

[Javascript has Unicode Problem](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode)

[Javascript Unicode](https://dmitripavlutin.com/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-unicode/)

Comment: Thank you so much for such instant respond. I understand strings could be different when they are even visually same. While in my case I need to get true in a if statenent. And when I compare them I did normalize. And I assume they will be same after normalized. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just check these examples here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize

Comment: I am sorry I could not find any new information from that example. It seems that it is a example for normalize function. And it worked if I have 2 string variable assigned in the code, but it will not workif I try to normalize a string that is from input text box.